# Mangaging an EditText states in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi i have a login form which has two EditText's one for email one for password and a sign in button when the user presses the button i want to do some verification of the forms. for example if nothings been inputted into the EditText's change the hint color and text of the EditText's heres what i have tried so far. i'm getting it so it logs out as being "" but it's not changing the hints.

```
Editable emailInputEditable = emailInput.getText();
    String emailInputString = emailInputEditable.toString();
    Editable passwordInputEditable = passwordInput.getText();
    String passwordInputString = passwordInputEditable.toString();

    Log.v("loginForm", "emailInputString = " + emailInputString);
    Log.v("loginForm", "passwordInputString = " + passwordInputString);

    if(emailInputString ==""){emailInput.setHint("Please enter your email");}
    if(passwordInputString ==""){passwordInput.setHint("Please enter your password");}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
if(emailInputString.length==0){emailInput.setHint("Please enter your email");}
    if(passwordInputString.length==0){passwordInput.setHint("Please enter your password");}
```

To disable signin button use below code

```
if(emailInputString.length==0 && passwordInputString.length==0)
signbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: on the reference of signin button call setVisibility(View.Gone);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(emailInputString.equals("")){emailInput.setHint("Please enter your email");}
if(passwordInputString.equals("")){passwordInput.setHint("Please enter your password");}
```

You put this code into button click event

Answer (score 0):

To compare Strings use `equals()` ...

Edit. too late :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(emailInput.getText()){

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordInput.getText())){

                // Perfom your logic here..

            }else
                passwordInput.setError("Please enter your password");

        }else
            emailInput.setError("Please enter your email..");
```

Happy Coding :)